# Как передать параметр к get-запросу

Tags: php, laravel, get

Собственно, у меня есть код, который должен вернуть кол-во юзеров, состоящих в группах в определенном daterange. Как мне создать параметры start_date и end_date к get запросу, чтобы я мог, например, через postman сделав get запрос на ссылку вида `example.com/participant_by_daterange?start_date=01.01.19?end_date=02.02.19`

> Route::get('participant-by-daterange', ParticipantCountsController@ParticipantCountsWithGroups')

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use app\Group;
use app\Participants;
use Carbon\Carbon;


class ParticipantCountsController extends Controller
{
  public function ParticipantCountsWithGroups()
  {
        $dateRange = "DD.MM.YY-DD.MM.YYYY";
        $splitTimeStamp = explode("-", $dateRange); 
        $start_date = $splitTimeStamp[0];
        $end_date = $splitTimeStamp[1];

        $participants = Participant::whereHas('groups', function($q) use ($start_date, $end_date){
          $q-> whereBetween('start_date',[new Carbon ($start_date), new Carbon ($end_date)]);
    })->get();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Параметры передаются по типу /link?param1=test **&** param2=test (а не все ?, как Вы написали. Но это так...)

Передайте Вашему методу в контроллере реквест и получайте уже внутри значения.

Например:

```
public function test(Request $request){
    echo $request->start_date . '<br/>' . $request->end_date;
}
```

[image: Результат]

Comment: у меня такой прикол, что в Postman пишет следующее (1/1) FatalThrowableError
Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Participant' not found , почему он пытается найти данный контроллер, я не понимаю

Comment: @Yevgen, не подключена модель Participant (у Вас есть Participants, но это же не одно и то же). Модели нет - laravel думает, что это класс, находящийся по неймспейсу. В каталоге такого контроллера нет, вот и ошибка, что класс не найден.

Comment: да, я это уже исправил, спасибо, но теперь я получаю лишь пустую страницу

Comment: @Yevgen Ну так что указали в контроллере, то и получили. Вы не выводите представление, не пишите ничего через echo, не вардампите данные (dd, var_dump и т.п), не возвращаете значения. Вы просто получили коллекцию при помощи запроса из БД и поместили её в переменную $participants.
Как сделаете что-нибудь с этой переменной, так и будет что-то выводиться.
Можете вот так в конце написать:
    return response()->json($participants->count()); 
или просто 
    return $participants->count();
если не нужен json

Comment: спасибо большое, вы мне очень помогли, но он выводит мне "0", словно говоря о моих познаниях :( , хотя записи есть, видимо ошибка в логике кода где-то